# EntityManager + @Transactional

Tags: spring, transactional

```
@Service
@Repository
@Transactional
public class VideoService  {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public void save(Video video) {

        Video video1 = new Video();

        entityManager.persist(video1);

    }



<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="video_pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" >
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>


<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/video" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>     

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="video_pu"/>
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />      
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
           <property name="showSql" value="true" />
           <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
           <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </bean>
     </property>

    </bean>



    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
       <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>


    <!-- post-processors for all standard config annotations -->
    <context:annotation-config/>
```

The transaction in service method save(Video video) is never started so also never commited. Where is the error? When I use EntityManagerFactory it works perfectly, but I don't want to explicitly begin and commit transaction. I want to use it with @Transactional annotation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to use an interface for the transactional annotations to be applied, e.g. `VideoService` and `VideoServiceImpl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@beerbajay is correct, @Transactional will need a dynamic proxy to be created on your bean to apply the transactional logic, which can be created if your Service has an interface, since in your case it doesn't an alternate would be to instruct Spring to create class based proxy, the following way:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class='true/>
```

Comment: how do i achieve this on a No xml configuration ?

Comment: Add @EnableTransactionManagement in your Config class