# EnityManager does not generate delete query

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I'm trying to delete an entity but the delete query is not generated and there's no error shown in the console :

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void removeClassObject(MyClassObject classObject) {
    MyClassObject ip = entityManager.find(MyClassObject.class, classObject.getId());
    entityManager.remove(ip);
}
```

Take notice : @Transactional is from springFramework package

**EDIT :**

All my configuration are ok, because I already have the merge and persist functions doing there job without any problem it's just the remove method which doesn't generate any sql query and does not remove the given entity.

**EDIT 2 :**

This is how I obtain my entityManager :

```
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

Comment: you mean you dont see the sql delete query or it doesnt take place?

Comment: I don't see the delete sql qyery

Comment: So it’s a matter of logging then?

Comment: No, the sql query is not generated and the entity is not deleted

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **@Transactional** annotation, you should consider using interface for your service, and not only implementation.

**@Transactional** will need a **dynamic proxy** to be created on your bean to apply the transactional logic, which can be created if your Service has an interface. Otherwise you would need to manage transaction on your own.

> In answer I assume that you create entity manager with
>   @PersistanceContext annotation and your service has no interface.

For mor information : [Spring transactions](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)

**EDIT:**

Also make sure, that you have enabled transactions in your configuration. Look here for similar error but with wrong configuration [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015854/entitymanager-transactional)

Comment: I'm already implementing an interface, I added the @Override annotation in my edit

Comment: how do you obtain your EntityManager? @MoatezBouhdid

Comment: All my configuration are ok, because I already have the merge and persist functions doing there job without any problem it's just the remove method which doesn't generate any sql query and does not remove the given entity

Comment: I reask my previous question "how do you obtain your EntityManager? "? With @PersistanceContext or with EntityManagerFactory?

Comment: with @PersistanceContext

Comment: btw no sql is generated, but did it has effect on database? I am asking if it removed but only hadn't shown logs.

Comment: No, the line is not removed from the database

Comment: Is it possible that you have some relation with this entity where you use it as optional = false?
Read here the anwser, maybe it will help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349213/hibernate-entitymanager-remove-referenced-entity-not-working

Comment: No, I don't have that, I already have multiple entities with a fully functionnal DAO layer and MyClassObject entity is nearly the same as the others

Comment: Try adding entityManager.flush() after removing and see if you get any error or it will work just fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169172/discussion-between-moatez-bouhdid-and-rjiuk).